# How to deal with multiple threads with multiple scanners (multiple resources)?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get data from four different sources with four scanners. I do realize that I need to use threads. But here's the error message:

P.S = paths for the files were fine before using thread. ( I was using one file, path was ok.)

null
null
null
null
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 41705
    at getText.getCities(getText.java:132)
    at getText$1.run(getText.java:23)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 41705
    at getText.getNames(getText.java:112)
    at getText$2.run(getText.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**Code Itself**

public class getText {

```
static int ln = 41705;
static String [] icaos = new String[ln];
static String [] iatas = new String[ln];
static String [] names = new String[ln];
static String [] cities = new String[ln];

public final Runnable typeA;
public final Runnable typeB;
public final Runnable typeC;
public final Runnable typeD;

public getText() {
    typeA = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getText.this.getCities();
        }
    };


    typeB = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getText.this.getNames();
        }
    };

    typeC = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getText.this.getIcao();
        }
    };

    typeD = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getText.this.getIata();
        }
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getText x = new getText();
    new Thread(x.typeA).start();
    new Thread(x.typeB).start();
    new Thread(x.typeC).start();
    new Thread(x.typeD).start();

    System.out.println(icaos[32541]);
    System.out.println(iatas[32541]); 
    System.out.println(names[32541]); 
    System.out.println(cities[32541]); 

}

public void getIcao () {
    try {

        int i=0;
        InputStream icao_stream = new FileInputStream("src/icao.txt");
        Scanner icao_s = new Scanner(icao_stream);
        icao_s.useDelimiter(",");
        while(icao_s.hasNext()) {
            icaos[i] = icao_s.next();
            i++;
        }

        icao_s.close();
        icao_stream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void getIata() {
    try {
        int i=0;
        InputStream iata_stream = new FileInputStream("src/iata.txt");
        Scanner iata_s = new Scanner(iata_stream);
        iata_s.useDelimiter(",");

        while(iata_s.hasNext()) {
            iatas[i] = iata_s.next();
            i++;
        }

        iata_s.close();
        iata_stream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void getNames() {

    try {
        int i=0;
        InputStream names_stream = new FileInputStream("src/names.txt");
        Scanner names_s = new Scanner(names_stream);
        names_s.useDelimiter(",");
        while(names_s.hasNext()) {
            names[i] = names_s.next();
            i++;
        }

        names_s.close();
        names_stream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void getCities() {
    try {
        int i=0;
        InputStream cities_stream = new FileInputStream("src/cities.txt");
        Scanner cities_s = new Scanner(cities_stream);
        cities_s.useDelimiter(",");
        while(cities_s.hasNext()) {
            cities[i] = cities_s.next();
            i++;
        }

        cities_s.close();
        cities_stream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: the error clearly says that you are trying to access `cities[41705]` which does not exist. It also means `cities.txt` has more than 41705 records

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I corrected ln input which has 41780 and get no error now. However, it still returns null.

Comment: You do not *need* to use threads. You *may* use them. For such a simple task (i.e file reading and scanning), it is probable that multithreading has little to no effect, since the bottleneck is usually in IO (the reading) itself, not the file interpretation, so I would advise checking if you really do *need* multithreading - unless this is an exercise of sorts.

Comment: now i'm able to return search results without threads and with four different input stream and scanners. But it makes program slower though.

Comment: @mduden it is slower, i'll take your word for it. But compared to what ? To the implementation you shared in the question ? That may be irrelevant because 1) this implementation fails, (hence your question) and 2) it does not wait for the threads to finish their work before exiting. So what are you comparing against ? (And then again : *maybe* a threaded version is faster, it's not just a fact that you can count on without measuring. It might also be faster when the system is not loaded, but slower when it is).

Comment: @GPI sorry for the undetailed reply. I designed this code actually for an android fragment, so when a user hits a button, it searches a string that is a user input in those 4 txt files and then returns data due to the correct index. I tried to understand scanners in java first.

Now, I realized that when user opens related fragment, it seems slower. So, I have decided to load first two scanners in onCreate and second two scanners at onClick.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem now is you have started your threads, but the control returns immediately to the main thread and your other threads are not finished working by then. What you need is to wait for those threads to finish working and then check for results. There are multiple ways to achieve that. A simple one is to change your `main` to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getText x = new getText();
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    threads.add(new Thread(x.typeA));
    threads.add(new Thread(x.typeB));
    threads.add(new Thread(x.typeC));
    threads.add(new Thread(x.typeD));
    threads.forEach(t -> t.start());
    threads.forEach(t -> {
        try {
            //this makes the main thread to wait for thread "t" to finish
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // log or throw or anything you need to do
        }
    });

    System.out.println(icaos[32541]);
    System.out.println(iatas[32541]);
    System.out.println(names[32541]);
    System.out.println(cities[32541]);
}
```

This is not the most optimal solution but the simplest one. Others better options would be to use a `CyclicBarrier` or `ExecutorService` among others.

Comment: Wouldn't using an `ExecutorService` be more appropriate?

Comment: I see this is now corrected by an edit... (Previous comment : This will launch the Nth thread only after the N-1th is over. Might as well not use threads at all).

Comment: @Abra, yes that would be a better solution, but I wanted to answer close to the approach already taken in the question.